# Remove class attribute in inherited class Python

Tags: python, inheritance, class-attributes

Consider such code:

```
class A ():
   name = 7
   description = 8
   color = 9

class B(A):
   pass
```

Class B now has (inherits) all attributes of class A. For some reason I want B not to inherit attribute 'color'. Is there a possibility to do this?
Yes, I know, that I can first create class B with attributes 'name' and 'description' and then inherit  class A from B adding attribute 'color'. But in my exact case, B is actually a **reduced** version of A, so for me it seems more logical to remove attribute in B (if possible).

Comment: If B is a reduced version of A, why doesn't A extend B instead of the other way round?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to [change your class hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674597/remove-class-attribute-in-inherited-class-python/3674714#3674714) so you can get the classes you want without any fancy tricks.

However, if you have a really good reason not to do this you could hide the `color` attribute [using a Descriptor.](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors)  You'll need to be using new style classes for this to work.

```
class A(object):
    name = 7
    description = 8
    color = 9

class Hider(object):
    def __get__(self,instance,owner):
        raise AttributeError, "Hidden attribute"

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        raise AttributeError, "Hidden attribute"

class B(A):
    color = Hider()
```

You'll then get an `AttributeError` when you try to use the `color` attribute:

```
>>> B.color
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __get__
AttributeError: Hidden attribute
>>> instance = B()
>>> instance.color
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __get__
AttributeError: Hidden attribute
>>> instance.color = 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in __set__
AttributeError: Hidden attribute
```

Comment: @Graf - Changing the class hierarchy was in @Duncan's answer first - I just linked to it - so I think you should accept his answer really.

Answer (score 8):

You can supply a different value for `color` in B, but if you want B not to have some property of A then there's only one clean way to do it: create a new base class.

```
class Base():
    name = 7
    description = 8

class A(Base):
    color = 9

class B(Base):
    pass
```